# Appending data frame1 with columns from data frame 2, row names

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to combine two tables in R, so that the resulting table will get values from both table 1 and 2.

```
df1<-data.frame(Name = c("Gene_1", "Gene_2", "Gene_4", "Gene_3"), "1"=c(0,1,2,6), "2" = c(5,6,7,5), "3" = c(9,8,7,7), check.names=FALSE)

> df1

    Name 1 2 3 
1 Gene_1 0 5 9
2 Gene_2 1 6 8
3 Gene_4 2 7 7
4 Gene_3 6 5 7


df2<-data.frame(Name = c("Gene_2", "Gene_4", "Gene_5"), "1" = c(0,2,3), "2" = c(3,2,1), "3" = c(4,3,2), check.names=FALSE)

> df2

    Name 1 2 3 
1 Gene_2 0 3 4
2 Gene_4 2 2 3 
3 Gene_5 3 1 2
```

the result should be something like:

```
 1 Gene_1 0 5 9 NA NA NA
 2 Gene_2 1 6 8 0 3 4 
 3 Gene_3 6 5 7 NA NA NA 
 4 Gene_4 2 7 7 2 2 2 
 5 Gene_5 NA NA NA 3 1 2
```

I feel that there must be some kind of easy way of doing it, rather than looping... It is not essential for output to sort the columns by any order, I just want to make sure that the right value goes in the right place. I've looked trough the forum, but still stuck(
Thank you,
Beth

Answer (score 4):

`merge` gets you there:

```
merge(df1, df2, by='Name', all=TRUE)

##     Name 1.x 2.x 3.x 1.y 2.y 3.y
## 1 Gene_1   0   5   9  NA  NA  NA
## 2 Gene_2   1   6   8   0   3   4
## 3 Gene_3   6   5   7  NA  NA  NA
## 4 Gene_4   2   7   7   2   2   3
## 5 Gene_5  NA  NA  NA   3   1   2
```